# How do I make a slide left/right menu in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-activity, slide

I'm trying to create a small game on Android and have some questions on a specific section of my game. I'm fairly new to android so please excuse if I don't have a full understanding of certain things.

When clicking "play" I'd like to view slide-able menu that makes it able for the user to swipe left and right to choose a level. Overtime I will be adding few more levels but have 2-3 of them now.

What would be the best way to do this? Is it best to implement a fragment for each "level page" or create entirely new activities?

My project is compatible for Android ver. 2.3.3 and above, so it's automatically included the "appcompat_v7" project. (I don't know if that makes a difference).

I've pasted my code below if needed:

```
package com.example.snake;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SnakeLevelSelectActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_snake_level_select);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.snake_level_select, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_snake_level_select, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

What I intended to do was create several fragment classes and animate between the fragments when the user swipes. I also have issues understanding on how to use several fragments with the "PlaceHolderFragment" class, since the solutions I've found on SO have been different. This is an entirely question, but would be appreciated if it was answered as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the best way to do this? Is it best to implement a fragment for each "level page" or create entirely new activities?

This is exactly what a `Fragment` is for. What you are looking for is already there and named [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Using ADT and Eclipse you can even create an `Activity` with this already implemented. Use the "Navigation type" combobox for that purpose:

[image: Screenshot of Activity Wizard]

You can also choose "Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager)", which will enable Tabs in the `ActionBar` and make sure that you can switch to different Fragments using both the swipe gesture as well as the tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does using ViewPager differ form using Navigation Drawer, which is suggest as another answer?

Comment: They are two completely different things. A `ViewPager` lets you swipe through different pages (i.e. fragments in this context). A navigation drawer is a menu that can be pulled in from the left and is meant to be used for the navigation throughout your application. Just take a look at some examples and screenshots.

Comment: @Vanquiza what exactly did you need? a sliding menu or a swipable page? navigation drawer offers you sliding menu like the facebook app.

Comment: @meda I need swipe-able pages. I formulated myself wrong, since I didn't know how to explain what I was looking for. I'd like it to swap to a new page when the user swipes left or right. Although I don't want tabs that I've seen many use with ViewPager.

Comment: @Vanquiza Using Tabs is not a necessity. Its even easier without them. You might want to take a look at [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJeeZHFgLfc&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo) YouTube series describing all of this in great detail.

Comment: Thank you very much, that tutorial was a GREAT help. A ViewPager and and how to use it was exactly what I was looking for. I'm greatful for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Android now has this built-in in the SDK.

They call it the [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Look up the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) it contains [sample project](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip), it is very easy to implement.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but isn't the question about a left/right swipe gesture, i.e. a ViewPager?

Comment: @KarolBabioch It's not so clear but based on the title `How do I make a slide left/right menu in Android?` I thought thats what it's reffering to. maybe we should ask OP to make sure?